# Slow startup time Jhipster 3.0 application on Digitalocean using ubuntu-docker

Tags: jhipster

I want to ask about my jhipster 3.0 generated application
I was generate jhipster 3.0 application

This is my .yo.rc.json file

```
{
    "generator-jhipster": {
    "jhipsterVersion": "3.0.0",
    "baseName": "sfaweb",
    "packageName": "com.codesolution.sfa",
    "packageFolder": "com/codesolution/sfa",
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "authenticationType": "session",
    "hibernateCache": "no",
    "clusteredHttpSession": "no",
    "websocket": "no",
    "databaseType": "mongodb",
    "devDatabaseType": "mongodb",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mongodb",
    "searchEngine": "no",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "rememberMeKey": "c566b7acc3ae6491cd93f66f816bea4296598be6",
    "useSass": false,
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "testFrameworks": [],
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "languages": [
      "en"
    ]}
}
```

I using docker from jhipster/jhipster

Then follow an instruction from 
https://jhipster.github.io/installation/

I running in dev mode,
This is my startup script

```
./mvnw -Dspring.data.mongodb.host=${MONGO_PORT_27017_TCP_ADDR}
```

This is screenshot after startup, it takes 1225.074 seconds.

[Startup screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiXy1.png)

I'm running on ubuntu
1 GB Memory / 30 GB Disk / SGP1 - Ubuntu Docker 1.10.3 on 14.04

Please help me, how it took so long?
Am i miss something here?

Comment: Liquibase connects to your mongo instance; Cold Tomcat cold start etc, HDD speed

Answer (score 0):

You posted a comment on Docker Hub, but I don't think it's related to our image jhipster/jhipster

On your screenshot, it stucks during 20min, between "web application fully configured" and "running with spring profiles"

Can you try with a simple configuration (all by default), with H2?